# How to find OAuth client id without google developer

Tags: javascript, oauth

I got an error when dealing with OAuth: The OAuth client was not found. Thats because I don't know my OAuth id. All the solutions contain google developer. I don't use that.

Comment: What is your oAuth provider?

Comment: I am using OAuth2 to allow users to sign into google, if that's what your asking

Comment: Well in order to use their OAuth API you have to have a google developers account so you can setup your access

Comment: So I cant make a google+ login?

Comment: You can, but you have to have a developer account so that you can identify your app that is using it. How else would a user know what they are actually signing into and allowing to get their information.